# SWIG has no output directory when installing ftdi

Tags: python, swig, ftdi

I'm trying to use `ftdi` in python on OSX. I thought I installed everything correctly (including dependencies and all), but when i try to `import ftdi` in my code it says

```
File "simple.py", line 11, in <module>
    import ftdi
ImportError: No module named ftdi.
```

I went looking in the installation output and as it turns out I think there is a problem with swig. It says:

```
-- Building python bindings via swig. Will be installed under
```

Without anything being printed after 'under'. I'm completely new to this and I did not find a possible solution on google. Does anyone know what the problem may be and how to fix it? The full log can be found at the end of this post.

```
$ cmake  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/usr" ../
-- Build type: RelWithDebInfo
-- Boost version: 1.54.0
-- Doxygen found.
-- Generating API documentation with Doxygen
fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.
-- Detected git snapshot version: unknown
-- Building libftdi1++
-- Found SWIG: /usr/local/bin/swig (found version "2.0.11") 
-- Building python bindings via swig. Will be installed under 
-- Building ftdi_eeprom
-- Building example programs.
-- Building libftdi++ examples.
-- Boost version: 1.54.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   unit_test_framework
-- Building unit test
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/kv/Downloads/libftdi1-1.0/build

vpnb007:build kv$ make
Scanning dependencies of target docs
[  4%] Generating doc/html/index.html
Warning: Tag `SYMBOL_CACHE_SIZE' at line 341 of file /Users/kv/Downloads/libftdi1-1.0/build/Doxyfile has become obsolete.
To avoid this warning please remove this line from your configuration file or upgrade it using "doxygen -u"
[  4%] Built target docs
Scanning dependencies of target ftdi1
[  8%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/ftdi1.dir/ftdi.c.o
[ 12%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/ftdi1.dir/ftdi_stream.c.o
Linking C shared library libftdi1.dylib
[ 12%] Built target ftdi1
Scanning dependencies of target ftdi1-static
[ 16%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/ftdi1-static.dir/ftdi.c.o
[ 20%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/ftdi1-static.dir/ftdi_stream.c.o
Linking C static library libftdi1.a
[ 20%] Built target ftdi1-static
Scanning dependencies of target ftdipp1
[ 24%] Building CXX object ftdipp/CMakeFiles/ftdipp1.dir/ftdi.cpp.o
Linking CXX shared library libftdipp1.dylib
[ 24%] Built target ftdipp1
Scanning dependencies of target ftdipp1-static
[ 28%] Building CXX object ftdipp/CMakeFiles/ftdipp1-static.dir/ftdi.cpp.o
Linking CXX static library libftdipp1.a
[ 28%] Built target ftdipp1-static
Scanning dependencies of target doc_i
[ 32%] Generating ../doc/xml/ftdi_8c.xml
Warning: Tag `SYMBOL_CACHE_SIZE' at line 345 of file Doxyfile has become obsolete.
To avoid this warning please remove this line from your configuration file or upgrade it using "doxygen -u"
[ 36%] Generating ftdi1_doc.i
[ 36%] Built target doc_i
[ 40%] Swig source
Scanning dependencies of target _ftdi1
[ 44%] Building C object bindings/CMakeFiles/_ftdi1.dir/ftdi1PYTHON_wrap.c.o
Linking C shared module _ftdi1.so
[ 44%] Built target _ftdi1
Scanning dependencies of target ftdi_eeprom
[ 48%] Building C object ftdi_eeprom/CMakeFiles/ftdi_eeprom.dir/main.c.o
Linking C executable ftdi_eeprom
[ 48%] Built target ftdi_eeprom
Scanning dependencies of target baud_test
[ 52%] Building C object examples/CMakeFiles/baud_test.dir/baud_test.c.o
Linking C executable baud_test
[ 52%] Built target baud_test
Scanning dependencies of target bitbang
[ 56%] Building C object examples/CMakeFiles/bitbang.dir/bitbang.c.o
Linking C executable bitbang
[ 56%] Built target bitbang
Scanning dependencies of target bitbang2
[ 60%] Building C object examples/CMakeFiles/bitbang2.dir/bitbang2.c.o
Linking C executable bitbang2
[ 60%] Built target bitbang2
Scanning dependencies of target bitbang_cbus
[ 64%] Building C object examples/CMakeFiles/bitbang_cbus.dir/bitbang_cbus.c.o
Linking C executable bitbang_cbus
[ 64%] Built target bitbang_cbus
Scanning dependencies of target bitbang_ft2232
[ 68%] Building C object examples/CMakeFiles/bitbang_ft2232.dir/bitbang_ft2232.c.o
Linking C executable bitbang_ft2232
[ 68%] Built target bitbang_ft2232
Scanning dependencies of target eeprom
[ 72%] Building C object examples/CMakeFiles/eeprom.dir/eeprom.c.o
Linking C executable eeprom
[ 72%] Built target eeprom
Scanning dependencies of target find_all
[ 76%] Building C object examples/CMakeFiles/find_all.dir/find_all.c.o
Linking C executable find_all
[ 76%] Built target find_all
Scanning dependencies of target find_all_pp
[ 80%] Building CXX object examples/CMakeFiles/find_all_pp.dir/find_all_pp.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable find_all_pp
[ 80%] Built target find_all_pp
Scanning dependencies of target serial_test
[ 84%] Building C object examples/CMakeFiles/serial_test.dir/serial_test.c.o
Linking C executable serial_test
[ 84%] Built target serial_test
Scanning dependencies of target simple
[ 88%] Building C object examples/CMakeFiles/simple.dir/simple.c.o
Linking C executable simple
[ 88%] Built target simple
Scanning dependencies of target stream_test
[ 92%] Building C object examples/CMakeFiles/stream_test.dir/stream_test.c.o
Linking C executable stream_test
[ 92%] Built target stream_test
Scanning dependencies of target test_libftdi1
[ 96%] Building CXX object test/CMakeFiles/test_libftdi1.dir/basic.cpp.o
[100%] Building CXX object test/CMakeFiles/test_libftdi1.dir/baudrate.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable test_libftdi1

//Comment: I forgot to save the full log, the next command has been re-exectued to be able to post it here, so it is not the original output
Karels-MacBook-Pro:build kv$ sudo make install
Password:
[  4%] Built target docs
[ 12%] Built target ftdi1
[ 20%] Built target ftdi1-static
[ 24%] Built target ftdipp1
[ 28%] Built target ftdipp1-static
[ 36%] Built target doc_i
[ 44%] Built target _ftdi1
[ 48%] Built target ftdi_eeprom
[ 52%] Built target baud_test
[ 56%] Built target bitbang
[ 60%] Built target bitbang2
[ 64%] Built target bitbang_cbus
[ 68%] Built target bitbang_ft2232
[ 72%] Built target eeprom
[ 76%] Built target find_all
[ 80%] Built target find_all_pp
[ 84%] Built target serial_test
[ 88%] Built target simple
[ 92%] Built target stream_test
[100%] Built target test_libftdi1
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "RelWithDebInfo"
-- Installing: /usr/lib/pkgconfig/libftdi1.pc
-- Installing: /usr/lib/pkgconfig/libftdipp1.pc
-- Installing: /usr/bin/libftdi1-config
-- Installing: /usr/lib/cmake/libftdi1/LibFTDI1Config.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /usr/lib/cmake/libftdi1/UseLibFTDI1.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/lib/libftdi1.2.0.0.dylib
-- Up-to-date: /usr/lib/libftdi1.2.dylib
-- Up-to-date: /usr/lib/libftdi1.dylib
-- Installing: /usr/lib/libftdi1.a
-- Up-to-date: /usr/include/libftdi1/ftdi.h
-- Installing: /usr/lib/libftdipp1.2.0.0.dylib
-- Up-to-date: /usr/lib/libftdipp1.2.dylib
-- Up-to-date: /usr/lib/libftdipp1.dylib
-- Installing: /usr/lib/libftdipp1.a
-- Up-to-date: /usr/include/libftdi1/ftdi.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_ftdi1.so
-- Up-to-date: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ftdi1.py
-- Installing: /usr/bin/ftdi_eeprom
```

Answer (score 0):

1. As of ftdi1.0 the import should be `import ftdi1`. Use 0.20 if you need `import ftdi`.
2. I had to add  /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ to the PYTHONPATH variable.